# A name for a claw-graph with paths attached to it

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I wanted to know if the following family of graphs has a name in graph theory: A claw with  paths of any length attached to the three free vertices of the claw. More formally, a connected   acyclic graph, with 1 vertex of degree 3 and the rest of degree 2 or less.

They're interesting because they arise in the study of graph minors. (In particular, if a graph of this type is a minor of another graph G, then it is also a subgraph of G.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any reason not to call them "subdivisions of claws," since that's exactly what they are; people working in subfactors [apparently](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86/a-name-for-star-graph-with-long-laces) call them "star-shaped," or I guess in this case "claw-shaped." I don't know of any other name for them, though.

Now that I think about it, aren't these exactly the trees with exactly three leaves? Do trees with a specified number of leaves have a name?

Comment: "Subdivisions of claws" probably seems best, since it's accurate and not confusing at all. 

One could call it a tree with three leaves only if you take a non-leaf as the root. If you consider one of the leaves as the root, then it has only 2 leaves. Since this is not unique, I don't think trees with a specified number of leaves have a name.

Comment: You could consider non-rooted trees, in which case the problem doesn't arise. But they don't seem to have a name in any case.

Answer (score 2):

In this paper such graphs are referred to as "spiders" and "subdivisions of stars":

http://doi.wiley.com/10.1002/jgt.20244

Comment: "Spider" is indeed a standard name for a graph with at most one vertex of degree greater than 2.  So Rune's graphs could be called "spiders with 3 legs" or "3-legged spiders".

Answer (score 2):

See also the question [A name for star-graph with long “laces”](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86/a-name-for-star-graph-with-long-laces).